# Material-ui show pop up autocomplete inside the textfield input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui v4 and I'm looking for a way to have an autocomplete functionality when someone writes inside the input but I want the pop up to be shown inside the textfield as the image below.

I looked everywhere but I couldn't find anything relative. Can this be done with Material v4?

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions for you:

[Material UI V4 Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/)

Or

[HTML Autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

The first solution, you have to provide your own list of autocomplete options while the second seems to use the browser default autocomplete options.

To Edit how it looks, then you are looking for CSS which is a different question

Comment: The material's autocomplete is shown directly below the textfield. I want to show it inside the input when the user writes.

Comment: well then put it into a div, make the textfield box invisible and make the div look like the textfield box.

Comment: You might also need to change the position property of the dropdown box so it expands the div.